# Replace two columns linux

Tags: linux, join, awk

I want to replace the second column of my first file

file 1:

```
2       rs58086319      0       983550  T       C
2       rs56809628      0       983571  T       C
2       rs7608441       0       983572  A       G
2       rs114910509     0       983579  A       G
2       var_chr2_983614 0       983614  T       C
2       var_chr2_983624 0       983624  A       G
2       rs115188027     0       983632  A       C
2       var_chr2_983636 0       983636  T       C
2       var_chr2_983650 0       983650  A       G
2       var_chr2_983660 0       983660  T       C
```

with the first column of my second file

file 2:

```
2_983550_T_C
2_983571_T_C
2_983572_A_G
2_983579_A_G
2_983614_T_C
2_983624_A_G
2_983632_A_C
2_983636_T_C
2_983650_A_G
2_983660_T_C
```

I've tried join and awk but somehow it doesn't seem to work. I suspect the fact that there's '_' on my second file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file2 have only one column so with awk.

```
awk -v f='file2' '{getline $2 <f}1' file1
```

If the separator of file2 is "_"

```
awk -v f='file2' '{getline a <f;split(a,b,"_");$2=b[1]}1' file1
```

Comment: That will fail quietly and/or cryptically in various situations. It's the wrong approach. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for why.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit puzzled why you need a second file. All information of `file2` seems to be encoded in `file1`. You could just do something like this :

```
awk '{$2=$1"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6}1' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to make `_` as field separator in Input_file2 then following may help you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1;next} (FNR in a){$2=a[FNR]} 1' FS="_" file2 FS=" " file1 | column -t
```

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next} (FNR in a){$2=a[FNR]} 1' file2 file1 | column -t
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `paste` and `awk`, e.g.:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ $2 = $NF } NF--' OFS='\t'
```

Output:

```
2   2_983550_T_C    0   983550  T   C
2   2_983571_T_C    0   983571  T   C
2   2_983572_A_G    0   983572  A   G
2   2_983579_A_G    0   983579  A   G
2   2_983614_T_C    0   983614  T   C
2   2_983624_A_G    0   983624  A   G
2   2_983632_A_C    0   983632  A   C
2   2_983636_T_C    0   983636  T   C
2   2_983650_A_G    0   983650  A   G
2   2_983660_T_C    0   983660  T   C
```